# Can I avoid windows snapping to main screen when I briefly lose my second screen?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

I have a Macbook Pro and almost always use it with an external, larger monitor, which I have set up so that it is right above the MBP's built in screen.  I have this same setup at home and at work.  This is my arrangement:

[image]

with the Dock at the bottom of the lower (built-in MBP) screen.  Usually I have most of my important windows positioned in the *upper* (external monitor) screen.  This provides the best ergonomics for me because I can look straight ahead instead of down.

When I leave one of these locations the MBP goes to sleep.  Then when I plug in at the other location, there is usually a moment (maybe 5 seconds) where the external monitor is not plugged in.  If that moment is too long, then all my windows reposition into the lower, built-in MBP screen.  Sometimes the windows end up shrunk in height to be very short as well.  So then, if I want to get back to where I was I have to drag all my windows (for umpteen apps) back up into the upper screen and expand the shrunken ones.

Is there any way to avoid this?  For example, can I cause the windows to have a preferred location that they could snap back to when possible?

I'm on OSX Lion (10.7.5).  This is a 15-inch MBP, new in spring 2011.

Answer (score 2):

[Stay](http://cordlessdog.com/stay/) should solve this for you.  It's not free, but it's not expensive either.

Comment: Looks intriguing!!